# Does $R^3$ with a line and a circle deleted deformation retracts to any simple space?

Tags: algebraic-topology

There are two cases for $R^3$ with a line and a circle deleted, i.e. the line goes through the circle or not. If the line goes through the circle, then the space actually deformation retracts to a torus. For another space, it is easy to compute the fundamental group, which is free group with two generators. But I feel difficult to see what simple space it can deformation retracts to. Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: The torus, considered as the boundary of a small neighborhood of the circle. Now that you know what you're looking for, see if you can picture the deformation retraction.

Comment: @MikeMiller  If the line does not go through the circle, the complement still deformation retracts to a torus?

Comment: Oh, I totally misread your question. No, in that case it's harder to calculate. It's still a 2-complex with the same homology as a torus, but the fundamental group is free on 2 generators. From that I would guess it's $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Actually I also guess it can be deformation retracts to this, but I am not very sure. Thanks any way!

Comment: Consider this instead as the complement of two unlinked circles in $S^3$ (perhaps both lying in the $xy$-plane in $\Bbb R^3$, centers on the $x$-axis). Then you can see the $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$ - the two circle factors are based at 0, and wind once through each of the circles we're deleting, and the 2-sphere is the $yz$-plane along with the point at infinity. The inclusion map induces an isomorphism on homology and on the fundamental group, so it must be a homotopy equivalence. I can see the picture, but would have trouble describing it.